# Testing a Form in FilamentPHP doesn't work

Tags: laravel-filament, filamentphp, pest, pestphp

I have an Order Form which I would like to test.
So I have an `OrderResource` and the url to the form is: `admin/orders/create` I believe that this corresponds to: `'create' => Pages\CreateOrder::route('/create')`,

So I wrote a test for this like so:

```php
livewire(CreateOrder::class)
    ->fillForm([
        'brand_id' => $brand->id,
    ])->assertFormSet(['supplier_id' => $suppliers->pluck('id')->toArray()]);
```

But when I run this I get:

```
Attempt to read property "form" on null.

      at vendor/filament/forms/src/Testing/TestsForms.php:125
        121▕     public function assertFormExists(): Closure
        122▕     {
        123▕         return function (string $name = 'form'): static {
        124▕             /** @var ComponentContainer $form */
      ➜ 125▕             $form = $this->instance()->{$name};
        126▕
        127▕             $livewireClass = $this->instance()::class;
        128▕
        129▕             Assert::assertInstanceOf(
```

MyCreateOrder class doesn't have a form property. I'm wondering where the $form property is set that renders the form when go to the aforementioned url

I have built this test based on the instructions [over here](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/testing#filling-a-form). And I am running on filament 3.2.7 in PHP8.2 and Laravel 10.10

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This error typically indicates that the Livewire component `CreateOrder` can't find the form. A possibility if because the test environment cannot have an authenticated user or the user haven't permission.

**Ensure User Authentication:**

Before attempting to access the form in your test, create and authenticate a user:

```
    $user = User::factory()->create();
    $this->actingAs($user);
```

This step ensures your test environment use an authenticated session.

**Manage Permissions with Roles (If Necessary):**

If your application uses a permissions package, like `Spatie's Laravel-permission`, ensure the test user has the necessary roles or permissions to access the form:

```
    $user = User::factory()->create();

    // Assuming 'super_admin' role has the required permissions
    $user->assignRole('super_admin');
    $this->actingAs($user);
```